# Bash - check number of arguments

Tags: bash

In my script I want to check if 1 or 2 arguments have been passed but my if statement is not working the way I expect it to.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ||  $# -ne 2 ]];
then
   echo "Needs 1 or 2 arguments"
exit 1
fi

hello() {
   echo "Hello world"
}

case "$1" in
       hello)
            hello
            ;;
       *)
            exit 1
esac
```

If I run

```
./script.sh hello
```

my If statement returns true and I get the echo statement "Needs 1 or 2 arguments". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `||` should be `&&`

Comment: `$# == 1`. So `$# -ne 1` is false, but `$# -ne 2` is true. `false || true` is true.